# how can I get my fixed-width mobile website to always appear "fully zoomed in"?

Tags: iphone, html, css, android, mobile

how can I get my fixed width site to always appear "fully zoomed in" on webkit (iphone and android) browsers?

right now, it looks fine on an iPhone and "too small/zoomed out" on an Android phones that have higher resolution.

i'm trying this viewport:

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=yes, width=device-width, target-densityDpi=device-dpi, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

Comment: dude did you find any good solution?

Answer (score 7):

The following worked for me. The page gets scaled down for medium and low density devices. Android 2.2 has some issues with handling meta tags.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, target-densitydpi=high-dpi" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the "initial-scale=x.x" number until it looks right:

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=yes, target-densityDpi=device-dpi, initial-scale=1.6" />
```

Comment: Setting initial scale manually is pointless. The 'perfect' value is different for different devices...